Does this JAVA_OPTS setting apply to Jenkins running as a Docker container?
We run our Jenkins instance as a Docker container, like this
docker run --restart=unless-stopped -d -p 8080:8080 -v /mnt/jenkins_master/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins_master --memory=24g 0123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jenkins_master:lts

In an attempt to solve Another "Failed to spawn helper" error on Lunux Ubuntu Jenkins build node?, I want to add a JAVA_OPTS setting suggested in Jenkins issue: FATAL: command execution failed, like this
docker run ... -e JAVA_OPTS="-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork" 0123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jenkins_master:lts

However, in the blog, folks run Jenkins as a service. Does the setting apply in my case running Jenkins as a container?
